# Why is Access returning a smaller table post-union, when union shouldn't add any rows?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm testing a process for regularly updating a table in Access, and I'm getting a behavior I don't understand.

I have my master table, and then a second table that is a subset of the master table (a simulated update to the master).

`Master` - 100,000 rows

`subMaster` - 500 rows (these 500 rows are already contained in `Master`)

The query:

```
SELECT field1, field2, field3 FROM Master
UNION
SELECT field1, field2, field3 FROM subMaster
```

Returns < 100,000 rows. `SELECT DISTINCT *` from either table does not remove any rows.

If this query behaved as expected, I'd expect it to return 100,000 rows, because every row in `subMaster` is contained in `Master`, so every row from `subMaster` should be excluded as a duplicate. How could the resultant table be shorter, and is there a way to get this to work the way I expect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SELECT DISTINCT *` is not the same as `SELECT DISTINCT field1, field2, field3`.

`UNION` removes duplicates, both within tables and between tables.  These three columns are apparently duplicated in `Master`.